# Is it possible, hypothetically, to get a 3D object rotating in a 4D space if we apply perpendicular axis theorem on that 3D object?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, vectors, geometry

The formula doesn't strictly need to be the one for 2D  objects some slight modifications are allowed. I am just speaking theoretically here.

Comment: Don't you need to assume the existence of another direction in order to apply the perpendicular axis theorem? So if you indeed had a 3D object rotating in some 4D space then voila, you have a 4D space

Comment: In 4 spatial dimensions, objects do not rotate about an axis. Instead, they rotate about a plane. So, if it even exists, it should really be called a "perpendicular-plane" theorem.

Comment: @ Vincent Thacker thanks for the info. I wasn't aware of it.